# WPF Datagrid COMException on using IncludeHeader ClipboardCopyMode 

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid, clipboard

In my WPF app, I am using a `Datagrid` control; in the control definition I defined `ClipboardCopyMode` property as 'IncludeHeader'.

```
<DataGrid Name="datagrid"  ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
</DataGrid>
```

At times, when I try to copy any data from grid, I am encountering `HRESULT` clipboard crash error -

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401D0): 
OpenClipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D0 (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN))
```

Any suggestions to resolve it. I looked at other posts, mostly they are about how to handle this scenario when you explicitly use the `Clipboard` related methods but none related to `Datagrid`.

Comment: having exactly the same problem with my app. Added a DataGrid, which is displaying data. The app was working fine, until I switched to VS2012 and .net4.5.  After that, when I copy the content to clipboard,  the app crashes

Comment: The answer to [Arsen's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769264/openclipboard-failed-when-copy-pasting-data-from-wpf-datagrid) on this helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Found this from Andrew Smith at http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/t/35379.aspx -

> Technically only 1 process can open the clipboard so if another
>   process has it opened the subsequent requests will fail until the
>   first releases the clipboard. This was sort of handled in the WinForms
>   Clipboard class where it would retry the set with a delay in between
>   each try but the WPF clipboard class doesn't do this so if it fails on
>   the first show the exception occurs. Even then we should probably
>   catch the exception and raise the clipboard operation error if it
>   still fails.

Same thing is explained and some ways to fix it are mentioned on this italian blog -

> [WPF DataGrid Clipboard BUG (?) & Work](http://blogs.wpfitalia.it/ainotame/archive/2011/03/22/WPF-DataGrid-Clipboard-BUGampWorkaround.aspx)
>
> [Google Translation](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://blogs.wpfitalia.it/ainotame/archive/2011/03/22/WPF-DataGrid-Clipboard-BUGampWorkaround.aspx)

Following MSDN forum thread suggests that this could be machine specific problem, can you reproduce this on other machines? -

> [CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN exception when copying to clipboard from a
>   DataGrid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi/wpf/thread/02b733e0-838d-46d6-952f-5483db32282d)

**Update:**

Blog link seems to be down but a cached version can be accessed through this link -

[WPF DataGrid Clipboard BUG (?) & Work (Cached translation)](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=it&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20120408210239%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fblogs.wpfitalia.it%2Fainotame%2Farchive%2F2011%2F03%2F22%2Fwpf-datagrid-clipboard-bugampworkaround.aspx&sandbox=1)