# Copy to clipboard failed in WPF Datagrid (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am having trouble copying cells from a WPF datagrid. I have a few other text editor windows (like Avalonedit) in the same app from where I can copy to Clipboard but not from the datagrid. Whenever, I try to copy even one cell I get the message "Open Clipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D0).

So I can copy paste everything else except from the datagrid. I tried the OpenClipboard and CloseClipboard approach but that didn't seem to work for me either.

I have looked at the approach mentioned here. (http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2012/06/27/when-the-clipboard-says-no/) but I am unable to find out how to override the method OnExecutingCopy unless I derive from a DataGrid and do something.

Answer (score 1):

@ssarangi

Hi ssarangi...I don't know if you ever solved this clipboard issue, but I encountered your question while trying to find a solution to a clipboard-contention problem some of my users are having intermittently. What I'm doing is a two-pronged approach:

1. Switched to using *System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject("string", false, retryTimes, retryDelay)*
2. Added logic to find the app with which I'm having the contention.

I answered another, similar question in which I included the code snippet, so if you're still looking for some assistance you can check it out and see if it helps: [OpenClipboard Failed when copy pasting data from wpf DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769264/openclipboard-failed-when-copy-pasting-data-from-wpf-datagrid/21311270#21311270)

In essence I used two *DllImport*'s for *GetOpenClipboardWindow()* and *GetWindowThreadProcessId()*, and then I get all the active *Process* objects via *Process.GetProcesses()* and iterate through them looking for a match on either the window handle from *GetOpenClipboardWindow()* or a match on *Process.Id* (the PID) I obtained via *GetWindowThreadProcessId()*.  This isn't a solution, but it *might* help identify what is locking you out of the clipboard.

The other thing I'm doing which again *might help* is switching to the *System.Windows.Forms* Clipboard class with the built-in retry loop for *SetDataObject()*.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but this solution is posted for completeness and is missing the use of a suited DataGrid event method signature associated with the DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs.

Clipboard.SetText can be flaky, not grabbing/setting the clipboard all the time.

Set "FullRow" at the SelectionUnit mode for dataGrid called myDataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" SelectionUnit="FullRow"></DataGrid>
```

We have a method myDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent that gets called for **each** row in the dataGrid to copy its contents to the clipboard. For example,for a datagrid with 7 rows this is called 7 times.

```
public int clipboardcalledcnt { get; set; } //CopyingRowClipboardContent invoked count
private void myDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    PathInfo cellpath = new PathInfo(); //a custom class to hold path info
    string path = string.Empty;

DataGrid dgdataPaths = (DataGrid)sender;
int rowcnt = dgdataPaths.SelectedItems.Count;

cellpath = (PathInfo)e.Item;

path = "Row #"+ clipboardcalledcnt +" Len="+ cellpath.Length.ToString() + ", path=" + cellpath.Path;

e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();

if (clipboardcalledcnt == 0) //add header to clipboard paste
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent("", null, "--- Clipboard Paste ---\t\t\n")); // \t cell divider, repeat (number of cells - 1)

clipboardcalledcnt++;
e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(path, null, path));

if (clipboardcalledcnt == rowcnt)
    clipboardcalledcnt = 0;
```

}